# Swiping gesture preventing click through below

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, androidx

I have an activity that is inflated with fragments.
[image: activity]

I need to observe an area of the activity (Fragment 1 and 2) for a swipe down gesture which will dismiss the activity.

I can't add the swipe gesture to the entire activity as Fragment 3 has a pull to refresh and they are conflicting motions. So far I have tried:

1. adding a view that covers fragment 1 and 2 and adding the listener there. However I need to handle ontouchevents in fragment 1. When I added the ontouchlistener to the new view it did dismiss the activity but prevented the clicking through to Fragment 1 as I had to return true from onDown to allow the onFling override to be hit

   ```
   private fun setUpSwipeToDismissActivity() {
   gestureDetector = GestureDetector(object : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
       override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent, e2: MotionEvent, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
           println("****** on fling")
           val diffY = e2.rawY - e1.rawY
           if (abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
               if (diffY > 0) {
                   finish()
                   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_alpa, R.anim.activity_slide_out_down)
               }
           }
           return false
       }

       override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
           return false
       }
   })
   swipe_detector_view.setOnTouchListener(touchListener)
   ```

   }
2. Moving the swipe gesture to fragment 1, but it can't handle click events as onDown returns true and then triggers the fling override.

So I need to be able to swipe to dismiss the activity but also allowing click events on Fragment 1.

Extra - Fragment 1 is a web view which has buttons to be clicked

Comment: I am not sure it will help, however when I implemented a gesture detector from this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-handle-swipe-gestures-in-kotlin look at step 4 and how to call it. But for me it worked perfectly.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is what I had working on the top red view but it prevents the click being passed to Fragment 1 which is the issue I'm having